# How to run a function periodically in django/celery without having a worker (or using Schedule)?

Tags: python, django

I would like to run my function do_periodic_server_error_checking every ten minutes, but I do not wish to:

- have it run on a worker - I'd like it to be run on the server itself (as far as I can see there is no way to get apply_async, delay, or @periodic_task to run on the server)
- use Schedule - (not sure why people are recommending a busy-waiting approach for a django server - maybe I'm missing something about the operation of Schedule)

My best idea so far is to schedule a cron job to make an HTTP request to the server, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way from within django itself?

Comment: A cron job that runs a management command?

Comment: Check this: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries and this https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules

Comment: Thanks oz19 - I may be confused, but that still requires celery to be running beat, which I'm unclear how to do in django - would it be part of the call:
app = Celery('celery'

Comment: So, I think I am lost too ;) Do you want to use Celery or not? If not, as you said, you can set a cron job at your server to make the request. I don't know another way "on django" to execute a job periodically.

Comment: Sorry, just doesn't look to me like the server can run those commands through celery... but I might be wrong.  Thank you for your time and I will use a cron job :)